# HowTo create InstallShield MSI with no files needed locally?

Tags: installshield

Hello everyone and good day!

**Question**: I had create a *Basic InstallShield Project* in my *MSVC2010*, added some files and primary outputs and press build. Project compiled normally: there was created MSI, setup.exe, setup.ini and (WTF?!) local directory structure of files, which I'm trying to install (for example, "Program Files\My Company\app.exe, ..." files was copied there). I throught that this is not needed folder, so copied my setup files (MSI, setup.exe, setup.ini) to another folder and start installation. When process of installation come on to copy state, installer gave me the error, that no required files (app.exe,...) was found.

Does anybody solve this problem? I think this is the simple one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer was found by myself, but thank you all any way...

To create a self-extracted install file you need to open "Releases" tab in your InstallShield Basic project and right click on configuration click "Release WIzard...".

All what I need is at this figure:

[image: Release Wizard...]

Answer (score 16):

You can achieve this by making some changes to the properties in solution explorer. This is so simple as you can compress all in single .exe file. Follow the given below step:

1. Right Click On Entire solution and Choose Properties as given below[image: First Step]
2. Second step as you can see the dialog box. click on configuration Properties[image]
3. Third Step [image]
4. Last step[image]

This is finest and easiest way to achieve the required task.

Comment: Just wanted to mention something that had me confused for all of five seconds, but may be helpful: If you go to ...'[YourInstallationProjectPath]\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\', you will see your single file there. At least this worked for me.

Comment: Fantastic. Straight-forward and it worked in the first try

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Select Compressed from Compression option in properties view.

Comment: This will create a Data1.cab file locally, still needed to be deployed with .msi. Is there any way to include all files, absolutely all inside the .msi file ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple use the "single image" build. Not cd nor dvd