# convert msi to exe with a command line option...

Tags: c#, command-line, windows-installer

i want to convert a msi file in to an exe file. When i run msi file with qn option with msiexec then my software install silently. But now i want to convert that msi file into .exe file , and that exe file runs msi file with ***msiexec /i "path of msi file" /qn*** option, any idea how to do it.

Comment: I suppose WinZip and a self-extracting exe could do this.

Comment: how can i define the option for command line to run that silently

Comment: and the client doesn't want self extracting exe , he simply wants to download it and after double click it will installed automatically..

Comment: Did you create the msi, or is it third-party? If you created it, what did you use? (WiX, InstallShield,  Nullsoft, etc.)

Comment: i am using install shield to create msi

Comment: If you are using Installshield you should set the release type to compressed in the release wizard. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making the setup yourself using **Installshield**, the tool itself should be able to create a **setup.exe** file by simply setting the release settings in the **[release wizard](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpReleaseWizIDERef.htm)** - I think it just entails setting the release **"Compressed"** but it could require further settings.

Please follow [**these help file instructions**](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpRelease_CreateSingleExe.htm) precisely. It is possible that some versions of Installshield (express, older versions etc...) does not have this option, but frankly I doubt it. It should be there once you look.

Perhaps also see [**this youtube.com demonstration of the release wizard**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2lW772u8QA) and this previous stackoverflow question: [HowTo create InstallShield MSI with no files needed locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992819/howto-create-installshield-msi-with-no-files-needed-locally)

Answer (score 10):

We can use 7zip SFX to create switch-less installers. here is a quick walk through

### Requirements

- **7Zip:** you can download latest version of 7zip from [Official Site](http://www.7-zip.org/).
- **7Zip SFX Module:** Official download page is [here](http://7zsfx.info/en/).
- **Resource Hacker or any other resource editor (Optional):** if you want to use a custom icon for you final executable you should use a resource editor app and replace the icon with your desired one. here is Resource Hacker app [download link](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/reshack_setup.exe) from it's developer website.

### Step1:

Create a `exec.bat` file in the same folder of your `msi` file and copy your `msiexec /i "path of msi file" /qn` in it. I used **Installer.msi** for my sample so here is my file:

```
@Echo off
msiexec /i installer.msi /qn
```

### Step2:

Compress `msi` and `bat` files to a `7z` archive.(you can download and install 7zip from [here](http://www.7-zip.org/)) in the sample I compressed my **Installer.msi** and **exec.bat** to a **installer.7z** archive.

[image]

### Step3:

Download and extract 7zSD (from 7zSfx link) and put the file in the same folder of archive, here is [direct link](http://7zsfx.info/files/7zsd_160_2712.7z) to it.

### Step4 (Optional):

We can change icon of the installer, to do this we should replace icon of `7zsd.sfx` file, in Resource hacker we should open `7zsd.sfx` and get to `IconGroup > 101 > 1049` and replace the icon with a desired one. then save the new sfx file in the same folder of generated 7z Archive. I saved mine as **7zsdInstaller.sfx**.

[image]

### Step5:

We should create a config file to tell the `Sfx` file what to do after extracting the archive, here is the config file for the sample:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
GUIFlags="8+32"
ExtractDialogText="My Sample Installer"
RunProgram="exec.bat"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

We should save it in the same folder of our 7z Archive, I named mine **config.txt**.

### Step6:

Now we should combine our file to a single executable, to do this, first we should navigate our Command prompt to a folder we hold our generated files and then we should execute following command:

```
copy /b 7zsdInstaller.sfx + config.txt + Installer.7z "installer.exe"
```

Now we should have a installer.exe in the same folder

[image]

Comment: @AnoopMishra, I updated the answer, you should download and install 7zip from provided link and then select both files, and compress using 7zip archiver

Comment: @KostiaMololkin `%errorlevel%` should do the trick, for example `echo %errorlevel%` prints exit code of last command executed in batch file

Comment: but where i shoud place %errorlevel% my self extracted exe return success(0) or 9009 when i place in exec.bat @Echo off
msiexec /i installer.msi /qn exit %errorlevel%

Comment: @KostiaMololkin it's a pseudo environment variable, you should first execute your command then check `%errorlevel%` information about the execution, so logically it should come in the following separate line after your command.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use install shield product of flexa software. You can compress your msi into .exe with all supported files used for extraction at the time of installation.

Comment: it is a conversion question, no need to buy/use heavy InstallShield