# How to select SingleImage for Install Shield project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield

I have an Install Shield project that produces a Disk Image and I want instead to produce a single click solution. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718057/how-to-create-a-single-setup-exe-with-installshield-limited-edition) which says to select **SingleImage**, however when I select my Install Project the only options in the Solutions Configuration pull down in the toolbar are Release and Debug. If I open the Configuration Manager the only options there for my Install Project under Configuration are Release and Debug. I'm running VS2013. How do I get the SingleImage option to appear?

[image: Config Properties Screen]

Although I'm running Visual Studio 2013 the InstallShield appears to be dated 2016
[image]

Comment: Have you tried Tofara Nderere's answer on that question?

Comment: @Michael Yes.  As I stated in the question, when I go to configuration manager and/or properties the only options available under Configuration are Debug and Release. See screen capture I just added to question showing pull down options for Configuration of SigToolUtilsInstall.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was thrown off by the linked question being about the Limited Edition. Things are more powerful (and less predefined) in the Professional and Premier editions. Visit the releases view to create a release, or configure its output to be like the SingleImage. See [HowTo create InstallShield MSI with no files needed locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992819/howto-create-installshield-msi-with-no-files-needed-locally), ignoring the high voted answer that applies to Express / Limited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HowTo create InstallShield MSI with no files needed locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992819/howto-create-installshield-msi-with-no-files-needed-locally)